# Prevent hint text use letterspacing in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, kerning

I have some issue in spacing/kerning with EditText in android. I want to use `android:letterSpacing` that already added in SDK 21, but i don't want to use the spacing in hint, just for the actual text only, is there any other way to do that? Before I make some custom EditText listener to switch the letterspacing when edittext is empty or not.

Comment: Do you find any solution, except change letter spacing programmtically?

Comment: @EduardKornev did you find a way to achieve this?

Comment: @gauravjain The same way, we changed letter spacing programmatically :(